# Re-rendering Reactjs array components

Tags: arrays, reactjs, performance, setstate

I am implementing a very simple charts page using React with the following components:
  Designer: has columns.
  Column: it renders a Chart if it has a tool.
  Chart: Will draw a Highchart chart.

The problem is the performance when i change the state of any column so i call `this.setState({columns: columnsArr})` in Designer, React will render all columns which will take a very long time if we have a 60 column for example.

I've read that React renders the component only if its props changed, so for column component, it should not render all columns if one column changed. So what am i missing here?

Here is my code :

`

```
class Chart extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);
    }

    handleDelete() {
        this.props.removeTool(this.props.index);
    };  

    render() {
        return (
            <div id={"Chart_"+this.props.index}>
                <div>
                    <button onClick={(e)=>{this.handleDelete()}} className="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><i className="fa fa-trash btn-danger"></i></button>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <HighchartsReact key={"H_" + this.props.index} highcharts={Highcharts} options={options} update={false} />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
};

class Designer extends Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);

        this.state = {
            columns: [
                { name: 'c1', hasTool: true },
                { name: 'c2', hasTool: true },
                { name: 'c3', hasTool: true },
                { name: 'c4', hasTool: true },
                { name: 'c5', hasTool: true }
            ]
        }
        this.toogleHasTool = this.toogleHasTool.bind(this);
    }
    toogleHasTool(columnId) {
        var columnsArr = this.state.columns;
        columnsArr.find(function (c) { return c.name === columnId }).hasTool = !columnsArr.find(function (c) { return c.name === columnId }).hasTool;;

        this.setState({ columns: columnsArr })
    }
    render() {
        var fn = this.toogleHasTool;
        return (
            <div id="container">
                {
                      this.state.columns.map(function (column, i) {
                        return <Column key={"Col_"+column.name} index={column.name} hasTool={column.hasTool} toogleHasTool={fn} />
                    })
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
};

class Column extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="col-sm-3" >
                {this.props.hasTool ? (<Chart key={"C_" + this.props.index} index={this.props.index} removeTool={this.props.toogleHasTool}> </Chart>) : ("")}
            </div>
        );
    }
};`
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try to extend `PureComponent` at your Column class. These components will re-render only if their state or props have changed. Note that it makes shallow (not deep) comparison of these objects. Thus if only one Column changes the others' **render(**) method won't be called.

Comment: For that matter, i implemented `
    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps)
    {
        return (this.props.hasTool !== nextProps.hasTool);
    }`
So now it is fast, but isn't that what React render() function should do by default?

Comment: It's recommended to extend PureComponent in this case, but yes  that will work for you, as well. Render()  function is not supposed to do that by default, since it's not always the case that changing ONLY props and state lead to re-render. You may have a look here : https://medium.com/@antonkorzunov/2-things-about-purecomponent-you-probable-should-know-b04844a90d4.